# Appending multiple csv files in to a single csv file using shell scripts

Tags: shell

I am trying to append multiple csv files in to one.
How can I enhance the below script so that an additional column is added. Let's call it "tag". The values in the tag should be the filename from which the record has been appended.

```
flag=0
for f in $@/*.csv;

do
k=$(wc -l<"$f" )
if [ $flag -eq 0 ];
then
  head -n $k "$f" > out.csv
  flag=1
else

  tail -n +2 "$f" >> out.csv

fi

done
```

Using @Shawn's approach below I am getting this:-

```
        $ cat TEST1/a.csv 
    h1,h2,h3 
    a,b,c 
    d,e,f 
    $ cat TEST1/b.csv 
    h1,h2,h3 
    1,2,3 
    4,5,6 
    $ awk 'NR == 1 { print $0 ",tag"; next } 
FNR == 1 { next } 
{ print $0 "," FILENAME }' TEST1/a.csv TEST1/b.csv 
    ,tag2,h3 
    ,TEST1/a.csv 
    ,TEST1/a.csv 
    ,TEST1/b.csv 
    ,TEST1/b.csv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this using awk:

```
$ cat a.csv  
header1,header2,header3
a,b,c
d,e,f
$ cat b.csv
header1,header2,header3
1,2,3
4,5,6
$ awk 'NR == 1 { print $0 ",tag"; next }
       FNR == 1 { next }
       { print $0 "," FILENAME }' a.csv b.csv
header1,header2,header3,tag
a,b,c,a.csv
d,e,f,a.csv
1,2,3,b.csv
4,5,6,b.csv
```

This: Treats the first line of the first file as a header line to print out, skips the first lines of all further files, and prints the remaining lines of all files, appending a column with the current filename to each one.

Comment: How can we use the above command in a loop so that it loops through all files within a folder?

Comment: @itthrill Why would you use a loop beyond the implicit ones in awk? `awk '...' *.csv`

Comment: And of course normal redirection of standard output if you want the results in a file.